# How do I restrict the number of user-logins per day?

Tags: security

is it possible to allow a user to login (to his ubuntu-account) only one time per day?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, you mean through SSH or local log-in?

Comment: Just curious what the use case for this would be. I can't really imagine a situation where this would be beneficial. Might this be an xy problem?